# restricted 3- space can be a field?

Tags: set-theory

if the topological boundary set is non-empty; we can put a field structure.
for example 3-space is not a field but R^3-{Ox,Oy,Oz} is a field.
i want to know can this be a theorem?

Comment: Every infinite set can be given a field structure. The result you are mentioning, that $\mathbb R^3$ is not a field, essentially only says that there is no field structure which is compatible with vector space structure on this space. If you remove the axes, this statement wouldn't even make sense.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065885/turning-mathbb-rn-into-field